# Is the set of decreasing sequences on the unit ball of $l^1[0,\infty)$ a compact set under the sup norm?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Formally, let
$$
\left\{\boldsymbol{x} = (x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots)\in [0,1]^{\mathbb{N}^*} : 1 \geq x_1 \geq x_2 \geq \ldots \geq 0 ~; \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} x_i \leq 1\right\}.
$$
Is this a compact set with the sup norm $\|\boldsymbol{x}\|_{\infty} = \sup_{i\in \mathbb{N}} |x_i|$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Consider a sequence $y_n$,
$$y_n=(\frac1n,\frac1n,\frac1n,\cdots,\frac1n,0,0,\cdots).$$

Comment: That's not a counter example under the sup norm.

Answer (score 0):

The anwser is yes. We prove the conclusion by arbitrarily choosing a sequence $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(n)}\}_n$ in $\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in\mathbb{R}_+^\infty|\sum x_k\leq1\}$ and demonstrating it has a limit point in $\Vert\cdot\Vert_\infty$ sense.

1. Due to **Helly's selection theorem**, there exists a subsequence, where for convenience we assumed to be $\{\boldsymbol{x}^{(n)}\}_n$, such that for every fixed positive integer $m$, $\{x^{(n)}_m\}_n$ converges to a number $x_m$ as $n\to\infty$. We denote $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$ by $\boldsymbol{x}$, and apparently $$\boldsymbol{x}\in\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots)\in\mathbb{R}_+^\infty|\sum x_k\leq1\}.$$
2. According to **Fatou's lemma**, we have
   $$\sum_{m\geq1} x_m=\int \boldsymbol{x}d\mu\leq\liminf \int \boldsymbol{x}^{(n)}d\mu=\liminf \sum_{m\geq 1} x^{(n)}_m\leq 1,$$
   where $\mu$ is the counting measure on $N_+$.
3. Since the conponents is decreasing, 
   $$x^{(n)}_m\leq1/m,\quad x_m\leq1/m,\quad n\in N_+,m\in N_+.$$
   $\forall \epsilon>0$, choose $N\in N_+$ such that
   $$|x^{(n)}_m-x_m|<\epsilon,\quad n>N,m\leq 2/\epsilon.$$
   Now $\Vert\boldsymbol{x}^{(n)}-\boldsymbol{x}\Vert_\infty<\epsilon,\ n>N.$

Comment: You cannot  make $\sum_{m\leq M} x_m \geq 1-\epsilon$. You seem to assume here that $\sum x_m=1$ whereas we only know $\sum x_m \leq 1$. Instead of $\sum_{m\leq M} x_m \geq 1-\epsilon$ you should say $\sum_{m> M} x_m \leq \epsilon$ But then the last part where you prove convergence in $l^{\infty}$ doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy you're right. I've corrected my proof, and "decreasing" is necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks, now that works.